# Apache Server Status Sending Reply with extrem high SS

Tags: apache-2.2, mpm-prefork

I'm currently running into a really strange issue.

My apache (prefork - 2.2.15) is running into MaxClients Limit and is therefore not responding to requests anymore.

The Server-Status is showing a lot of Requests in state `W` Sending Reply, but with a quite high SS value

This Apache Childs increasing over time, but never leave this state (until we gracefully restart apache)

```
    Srv     PID     Acc         M   CPU     SS      Req Conn Child Slot  Client       VHost                Request
...
    60-0    1383    0/111/300   W   3.71    3866    0   0.0 0.30    2.71    10.20.0.1   www.domain.com  GET /a.html
    61-0    1026    0/160/166   W   3.87    4593    0   0.0 1.35    1.35    10.20.0.1   www.domain.com  GET /b.html
    62-0    1338    0/21/21     W   3.59    4171    0   0.0 5.12    5.12    10.20.0.1   www.domain.com  GET /c.html
...
```

This are different Requests and I can't see any problem on this (php)Pages. Overall the load of this (unix) server is low.

My question is, should this requests (seems like they are still 'running') not be terminated after some time? Which timeouts are responsible for handling such situations? Hopefully you are able to give me some hints ;-)

Overall

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache status doesn't show any PHP scripts, but in case you actually are running PHP, have a look at [Apache Processes Hanging and Hitting MaxClients](https://serverfault.com/questions/185526/apache-processes-hanging-and-hitting-maxclients)